# Error in simplesamlphp_auth.module: no valid attribute set

Tags: 8

I'm configuring my application as a saml provider and for this I have used [simplesamlauth module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth). This module (simplesamlphp_auth) provides the ability to make a Drupal site into a SAML Service Provider (SP).

Now while configuring this module, I'm confused about the values that it will take as inputs.

[image]

I used SAML tracer, where I'm getting SAML response. Is it from here I will get any kind of attribute that need to be configure at /admin/config/people/simplesamlphp_auth/sync page?

Because right now it is giving me error:

> Error in simplesamlphp_auth.module: no valid \"nameid\" attribute
>   set.\" at
>   /var/www/html/modules/contrib/simplesamlphp_auth/src/Service/SimplesamlphpAuthManager.php
>   line 165",

What would be the unique identifier for the user and username for the user?

Answer (score 0):

The General values for same will be as follows:

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress

but if these not works you can also check the values in Metadata XML received from your IDP.